# "Often" position and the change of meaning

Tags: grammar

Do sentences 1 2 and 3 mean although I'm in the habit of reading the paper, I'm often too busy to read it, but sentence 4  means I am not in the habit of reading it?

1."Often, I don't read the newspaper."
2. "I often don't read the newspaper."
3. "I don't read the newspaper often."
=I'm in the habit of reading the paper, but I'm often too busy to read it.

4.I don't often read the newspaper." I rarely read the newspaper. I'm not in the habit of reading it.

If I am not mistaken regarding the meaning of the sentences above,  doesn't the idea change in the same way in the sentences below?

1. Often I don't feel hungry.
2. I often don't feel hungry.
3. I don't feel hungry often.​
   The sentences 1, 2, 3 it's not uncommon for me not to feel hungry. But sentence 4 sentence means "I don't usually fell hungry."
4. I don't often feel hungry

Comment: With regard to the newspaper ones, to me (3) and (4) both imply 'I seldom read a newspaper', while (1) and (2) _could_ mean 'I take a newspaper but often don't get the chance to read it', though this meaning would be clearer with _don't have time to_.

Comment: @KateBunting is it the same with the feeling hungry sentences too? Based on your comment I will correct my sentences and ask do 1.Often I don't feel hungry.

2 I often don't feel hungry mean it's not uncommon for me to feel hungry while 3. I don't feel hungry often and 4 "I don't often feel hungry" mean that it's common for me to feel hungry"?

Comment: I deliberately didn't mention the second set because they are harder to analyse! Basically, they all mean the same. If there's any difference, I feel that the first two could refer to specific occasions such as mealtimes - "Often (at dinner time) I don't feel hungry" - while the others mean that you seldom feel hungry at any time.

Comment: @KateBunting, and in the first set of sentences do the sentences require additional information to work? If I remove "the newspaper" would they work? as in 1."Often, I don't read."
2. "I often don't read."
3. "I don't read often."


4.I don't often read.

Comment: Antonia, to make line items appear one above the other, and not in a single line, use two spaces (by pressing the space bar twice at the end of each line).

Comment: I would understand _read_ without an object to refer to reading books, and I find (1) and (2) unidiomatic.

Comment: @KateBunting,  so sentences 1 and 2 need an object/additional information  to work, but the other sentences can be used as standalone sentences. Right?

Comment: _I don't often read, but when I do I like a good detective story_. It would be much harder to think of a context where _Often, I don't read_ would sound natural.

Comment: @KateBunting, thank you!!!